# How to conditionally include mounting a volume

Tags: powershell, docker

I've got a `docker run` command that looks something like this:

```
docker run `
-v C:\some\dir:/root/some/dir
```

What I'd like to do is to only include the volume mount if `C:\some\dir` exists but I can't seem to get the PowerShell syntax correct.

I tried the following but kept getting `"C:\\some\\dir\\" is not a valid windows path`. I'll use the real world code for clarity.

```
$awsPath = $null
if(Test-Path ~/.aws) {
   $awsPath = Resolve-Path ~/.aws
   $aws_mount = "-v ${awsPath}:/root/aws"
}

docker run `
$awsPath
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may not make a difference, but it's conceptually cleaner to pass the tokens as an _array_: `$aws_mount = '-v', "${awsPath}:/root/aws"`. I'm also curious where the doubling of the backslashes comes from. You can try with `/` as the path separator instead:  `$aws_mount = '-v', "$($awsPath - replace '\\', '/'):/root/aws"`

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I'll give the array a shot. I'll also look into the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character in Docker is the escape character. I think Docker tries to get around this by adding the double slash for you to escape the backslash. As I work around I use slash instead of backslash as lucky for us, PowerShell understands the slash when working with path names.

Please see example code below:

```
$awsPath = "c:\temp\aws"

if (Test-Path -Path $awsPath) {
    # Escape the backslash here as the backslash is the escape char in regex also
    $dockerAwsPath = $awsPath -replace "\\", "/" 
    docker run --rm -v ${dockerAwsPath}:/root/aws busybox ls -a /root/aws/
} else {
    docker run --rm busybox ls -a /root
}
```

And the output:

```
.
..
```

And now i create the folder:

```
New-Item -Path $awsPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
"Hello" | Out-File -FilePath "$awsPath/hello.txt"

if (Test-Path -Path $awsPath) {
    # Escape the backslash here as the backslash is the escape char in regex also
    $dockerAwsPath = $awsPath -replace "\\", "/" 
    docker run --rm -v ${dockerAwsPath}:/root/aws busybox ls -a /root/aws/
} else {
    docker run --rm busybox ls -a /root
}
```

and output:

```
.
..
hello.txt
```

So the path would look like this which both Powershell/Docker understand:

```
PS C:\temp> $dockerAwsPath
c:/temp/aws
```

If working with a Dockerfile, there are some details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#escape) about changing the escape character to something else. I haven't tried this but it might work as another solution.